# Portfolio page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am pretty new in asp.net. I am doing a project for the university and I want to put a portfolio page. In this page I want to have just images with links. I have a table in the database for the portfolio with field for the image which contains the image path.

Here is what is on the front end now, the static html:

```
    <div id="gallery">
            <div class="gallery_box"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_01_b.jpg" title="Nullam aliquam consectetur tortor, ac porta nisi ultrices ut."><img src="images/portfolio/image_01.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_02_b.jpg" title="Praesent luctus nisi rhoncus libero hendrerit ut tempus dolor."><img src="images/portfolio/image_02.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_03_b.jpg" title="Donec turpis nisl, malesuada in ultrices at."><img src="images/portfolio/image_03.jpg" alt="Image 03" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box gb_lmb"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_04_b.jpg" title="Pellentesque fringilla diam ac metus pulvinar lacinia."><img src="images/portfolio/image_04.jpg" alt="Image 04" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_05_b.jpg" title=" Fusce purus lectus, rutrum non ultricies eu, aliquet nec sapien."><img src="images/portfolio/image_05.jpg" alt="Image 05" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_06_b.jpg" title="Maecenas fringilla consectetur lacus, et sagittis felis ut."><img src="images/portfolio/image_06.jpg" alt="Image 06" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_07_b.jpg" title="Cras ullamcorper accumsan sem eu sollicitudin."><img src="images/portfolio/image_07.jpg" alt="Image 07" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_box gb_lmb"><span></span>
                <a class="pirobox" href="images/portfolio/image_08_b.jpg" title="Proin aliquet malesuada odio ac laoreet."><img src="images/portfolio/image_08.jpg" alt="Image 08" /></a>
                <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="cleaner"></div>
            <div class="paging">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.templatemo.com" rel="nofollow" target="_parent">Previous</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/1" target="_parent">1</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/2" target="_parent">2</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/3" target="_parent">3</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/4" target="_parent">4</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/5" target="_parent">5</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/6" target="_parent">6</a></li>
                    <li><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/7" target="_parent">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

How can I make this work with asp.net I think that I have to write a for cycle for example to get all the records from the database and then print them in the front end but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If your project is due tomorrow, then I'd say that you waited too long.

Comment: This is the last thing I got to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `<asp:Repeater />` control, it should look like that:

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrPortfolio" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="gallery_box">
                <span></span>
                 <%--Where in `<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>` "ImgUrl" should be replaced by your property name.--%>
                    <a class="pirobox" href="<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>" title="Nullam aliquam consectetur tortor, ac porta nisi ultrices ut.">
                        <img src="<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>" alt="Image 01" />
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="port_detail">Detail</a>
                    <div class="cleaner"></div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

And you can bind your PortfolioCollection in the code-behind (.cs) like that:

```
  rptrPortfolio.DataSource = YourPortfolioCollection;
  rptrPortfolio.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have added the repeater and configured it with the database:

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="portfolio" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:proekt %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [image] FROM [portfolio]">


       </asp:SqlDataSource>

I can't understand how to use your code and the code behind where do I put it I mean in the page load or somewhere else ?

Comment: it can be placed in the page_load.

Comment: What property should I put here: 
 <%--Where in `<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>` "ImgUrl" should be replaced by your property name.--%>

Comment: The `<asp:Repeater />` part is in the .aspx not in the .aspx.cs, if you are using a `DataTable` to fill that just use the columns name.

Comment: Yes it is there and in the aspx.cs in the page load I put only the rptrPortfolio.DataSource = YourPortfolioCollection;
  rptrPortfolio.DataBind(); but it gives me YourPortfolioCollection does not exist in the current context

Comment: YourPortfolioCollection has to be replaced by the DataCollection that you have!

Comment: here: <%# Eval("image") %> image is the name of the table where are the paths of the images. "YourPortfolioCollection has to be replaced by the DataCollection that you have" how can find what is the DataCollection I have

Once again excuse me for the dumb questions but I am a newbie...

Comment: I have placed portfolio as datacollection because this is the id of the datasource I have but now it gives me error Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'rptrPortfolio'.  Remove one definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is classic ASP.NET and not ASP.NET MVC

If you want to display multiple items in the same structure I'd recommend you use a [Repeater-control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's pretty flexible and easy to use.

Read your data from the database and bind it to the repeater. If necessary you can manually bind the data to each control in the OnItemDataBound-Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Grid View. And you can bind your data at page load

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                bind();
            }
        }
protected void bind()
{
    yourGridId.DataSource = yourdatasource;
    yourGridId.DataBind();
}
```